# XSLT select distinct values using attributes

Tags: xslt, select, unique, distinct

i'm trying to transform a list to a distinct values list using XSLT.

Input:

```
<object name="obj1"/>
<object name="obj2"/>
<object name="obj1"/>
```

Desired output:

```
<object>obj1</object>
<object>obj2</object>
```

Somebody an idea how to get it done either in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

THX

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use XSLT 2.0 and

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//object/@name)">
  <object><xsl:value-of select="."/></object>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//object" group-by="@name">
  <object><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></object>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: For me its coming this error `'distinct-values()' is an unknown XSLT function.`

Comment: You need to use an XSLT 2 processor to run that code.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do that. I am using c#

Comment: I got a link from your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020359/forcing-xslt-to-use-version-2-with-xslcompiledtransform). Thanks!

Comment: @MartinHonnen `distinct-values()` returns `xs:anyAtomicType` though. What if I have a function with return type `attribute()*` and I want to return de-duplicated attributes?

Comment: @MartynasJusevičius, I think you should raise that as a separate question, it is not clear if you want to de-duplicate the attributes based on node id or attribute value. But `<for-each-group select="$attribute-sequence" group-by="."><xsl:sequence select="."/></xsl:for-each-group>` for de-duplicating by attribute value should do. For node id using `$attribute-sequence/.` should do.

Answer (score 3):

**For XSLT 1.0**

objects.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="objects.xsl"?>
<objects>
  <object id="id1" name="obj1"/>
  <object id="id2" name="obj2"/>
  <object id="id3" name="obj1"/>
</objects>
```

objects.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="index1" match="*" use="@name" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <objects>
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[generate-id() = generate-id(key('index1',@name)[1])]">
            <object><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></object>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </objects>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is happening here:

1. With `<xsl:key name="index1" match="*" use="@name" />` you define an index for `key()` function named `index1`. It must be outside of `xsl:template` declaration.
2. With `match="*"` you define that it is suitable for all elements.
3. With `use="@name"` you define a search criteria for `index1`.
4. Now `key("index1","obj1")` will return an array consists of nodes where attribute `@name` equals `"obj1"`: [`<object name="obj1" id="id1"/>`,`<object name="obj1" id="id3"/>`].
5. You will need `generate-id()` function that generates unique ID for a given node.
6. Called with a parameter, generate-id(`<object name="obj1" id="id1"/>`) will return something like `"id0xfffffffff6ddca80obj1"`.
7. Called without parameters, `generate-id()` will return an ID for a **current** node.
8. You start `xsl:for-each` cycle for all elements `//*` with condition that `generate-id()` of current node must be equal to `generate-id()` of a first node from `key('index1',@name)` result. Which means it must be the first node itself.
9. You print current `@name` value with `xsl:value-of`. Since it happens only for a first element of `key('index1',@name)` result, it will be printed only once.