# forcing xslt to use version 2 with xslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt, .net-4.5

I have following xslt , I need to use xslt version 2.0 functions like 'format-date'. How do I declare the Xsl sheet to use version 2.0 using XsltCompiledTransform class (c#, .net 4.5).

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict"
               xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' 
               xmlns:var='urn:var' 
               xmlns:JS='urn:JS'
                >
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:variable name="n" select="1"/>
  <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          table{border-collapse:collapse;font-family:"Verdana";}
          table,td{border:1px solid black;color:black; background-color:white;font-family:"Verdana";}
          table,th{border:1px solid balck;background-color:black;color:white;font-family:"Verdana"; }
          .rt{color:red;font-family:"Verdana";}
          .nt{color:black;font-family:"Verdana";}
          .redb{color:yellow; background-color:red;font-family:"Verdana";}
          .greenb{color:white;background-color:green;font-family:"Verdana";}
          .blackb{color:white;background-color:black;font-family:"Verdana";}
        </style>
        <title>EDI validation Result </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p class="nt">
          EDI validation result  of the PO <span class="rt"><xsl:value-of select="info/pono"/></span>
          received from <xsl:value-of select="info/CustomerName"/>.
        </p>

        <table>
           <th class="blackb" >Position</th>
          <th class="blackb"> Item Code </th>
          <th class="blackb">UoM</th>
          <th class="blackb"> Ordered Qty .</th>
          <th class="blackb">Ship Request</th>
          <th class="blackb"> Net-Quoted </th>
          <th class="blackb"> Net-Catalog </th>
          <th class="blackb">Status</th>
          <xsl:for-each select="Table">
            <tr>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Status !=''">
                  <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="JS:IncBlines()"/>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="Position"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="ItemCode "/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="UoM"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="QtyOrdered"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="format-date(RequiredBy,'D1o [MNn] [Y0001]')"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="PriceQuoted"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="Net"/></td>
                  <td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="Status"/></td>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="JS:IncGlines()"/>

                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="Position"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="ItemCode"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="UoM"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="QtyOrdered"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="format-date(RequiredBy,'D1o [MNn] [Y0001]')"/></td>


                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="PriceQuoted"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="Net"/></td>
                  <td class="greenb"><xsl:value-of select="Status"/>OK</td>

                 </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>

        <xsl:if test="JS:GetBlines() &gt; 0"    >

          <p class="nt">

              The order validation has failed,

              The order will not be processesed as there are <xsl:value-of select ="JS:GetBlines()"/> lines in error.
              <p class="rt">

                The P.O is rejected as per agreed processing rules.


          </p>
          </p>

        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="JS:GetBlines() &lt; 1">
          <p class="nt">
          The Order validated succesfully.
          Will e-mail Order Acknoledgement (non-edi) shortly.
          </p>
        </xsl:if>

      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language='JScript' implements-prefix='JS'>

    <![CDATA[
    var j :int=0;
    var blines:int =0;
    var glines:int=0;
    function Inc(current)
    {j=j+current;

  return  j+current;
    }
    function IncBlines()
    {
     blines++;
    }
    function IncGlines()
    {
    glines++;
    }

    function GetBlines()
    {
    return blines;
    }
    function GetGlines()
    {
    return glines;
    }
]]>
  </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform is an XSLT 1.0 processor. To use XSLT 2.0 with .NET, you have two third party options, the .NET version of Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ or [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm). Saxon has an open source version HE and two commercial versions PE and EE, XmlPrime for commercial use requires a license.

Comment: Apparently, msxsl ns provides extended set of functions including format-date() for xslt 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 9):

As Martin wrote, Microsoft's processor only supports 1.0 - even now, in 2016.  I had a similar problem (I needed to do work with regular expressions within my XSLT) and I resolved it by **using inline C# to do the work**.

I based my solution on this example: **[XSLT Stylesheet Scripting Using <msxsl:script> (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx(v=vs.110).aspx)**

You'll have to add a few things to your `xsl:stylesheet` node.  Mine looks like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
```

Then, you'll define your script.  Mine was something like:

```
<!-- Script to check for URLs in values -->
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
      public string ExtractUrl(string str)
      {
          return Regex.Match(str, @"(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))").Value;
      }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

I was then able to invoke the function within my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="extractedUrl" select="user:ExtractUrl(.)"></xsl:variable>
```

It's not mentioned on the tutorial page, but where I processed the XSLT on the server, I also had to create an [`XsltSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) object to enable script execution:

```
XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(false, true); // enable script execution
XsltCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("template.xsl", settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

Of course, **consider security** - make sure your XSLT file contains only trusted and/or sanitized input if you're allowing the execution of arbitrary C# scripts.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to the approved answer, here's an expansion on @TonyP's comment on using Microsoft's `format-date`.

MSDN Documentation on format-date: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**Example**

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl"
>

<!-- ... --->
<td class="redb"><xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date(RequiredBy,'d MMMM yyyy')"/></td>
<!-- ... --->
```

NB: MS's options for formatting dates are far less rich that those available in XSLT 2.0 (see documentation); so I believe the `d MMMM yyyy` format is the closest you can get to the format you're after.